# AVR: target doesn't answer error

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

I was trying to overwrite the AVR Fusebytes  for AVR16A

```
sudo avrdude -p atmega16 -P usb -c usbasp -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m
```

before overwriting it was `l:0xe1 h:0x99`
after overwriting it gives an error .

```
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer.
1 avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
this check.
```

How do I recover from this mistake?

```
Edit: When I run with -F option 
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: Device signature = 0x88fbe8
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega16 is 1E 94 03
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to erase Flash. Erase by default will clear FLASH and lock bits.

check this [blog](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/260.html), though it is meant for ATMega32, it will work for any ATMega controller

Comment: But it will not clear the Fuse Bits.

Comment: updated the answer with a link, hope it helps

Comment: Looks like exactly my problem.